# translation using d3 with translation using data from an array in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to draw rectangles in an svg.
the rectangles needs to be translated and translation data is in array.

Here is the code

```
var vis=d3.select("#usvg");
var rectData=[10,21,32,43,54,65,76,87,98,109];

vis.selectAll("rect").data(rectData).enter().append("rect")
       .attr("width",10).attr("height",10).style("fill",'#cbdb53')
        .attr("transform",function(d){return translate(72,d);});
```

I want to get y coordinate of translation from rectdata.
How can I do this?Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line

`.attr("transform",function(d){return translate(72,d);});`

should be

`.attr("transform",function(d){return "translate(72," + d + ")";});`

Regards,
Igor